# What services are required for running SQLServer Express locally?

Tags: sql-server-express

I installed SQLServer Express recently (for doing some small tests at home), but chose to set all the services to manual by default (because I don't want the services running all the time, since I will only be using it infrequently). But after rebooting, SSMS could no longer connect to my local SQLExpress (naturally, as all the services were stopped). But when I went into the services console, I found SIX different SQL services! Which ones do I need to start in order to simply connect to the database in SSMS?

Here's what's listed in the Services Console:

- SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)
- SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)
- SQL Server Browser
- SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (SQLEXPRESS)
- SQL Server Reporting Services (SQLEXPRESS)
- SQL Server VSS Writer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" for certain. That's the database engine.

The "SQL Server Agent" service won't start in Express Edition. You can try, but it will give you an error message.

You'll probably want to start the "SQL Server Browser" service. But "it depends". If you connect as `YourSqlHost\SQLExpress`, you need the Browser service on--it matches the "SQLExpress" instance name to the port number it is running on. (A "default" instance of SQL Server doesn't need this--it always runs on port 1433...well, by default anyway.) A named instance of SQL uses dynamic port numbers. You could use SQL Configuration Manager and change to a static port. If you did that, you could connect as `YourSqlHost,xxx`, where `xxx` is your port number. *Then* you could turn the "SQL Server Browser" service off.

**Edit** The above applies to typical client/server connections over tcp. If you are running SSMS directly on the SQL host, you'll be connecting over shared memory. You may not need the Browser service running in that case. You should be able to verify this fairly quickly.

If you didn't choose Full Text Search during the install, you don't need to start "SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher". The same goes for SQL Server Reporting Services (aka SSRS).

I believe the "SQL Server VSS Writer" is related to VSS/VDI for backups related to snapshots. You probably won't need that.

Answer (score 0):

So after some trial and error, I have found some answers to my own question. This problem was complicated even further by the fact that the "**Service Name**" (which is displayed in the Services management console, is different than the "**Display Name**" (which is displayed in the Services tab of Task Manager). Here's a table of what I know so far:

```
Service Name        | Display Name                  | Notes
--------------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------------------
MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS    | SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)       | Required 
SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS | SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) | Used by DBAs (for jobs, backups, etc)
SQLBrowser          | SQL Server Browser            | Server/client setups (remote connections)
SQLWriter           | SQL Server VSS Writer         | For backup/restore(??)
ReportServer        | SQL Server Reporting Services | Used with Report Server
MSSQLFDLauncher     | SQL Full-text Filter          | Full-text filter is optional
                        Daemon Launcher (SQLEXPRESS)
```

So, strictly speaking, only the first service on this list is "required" when using SQLServer locally on one's own machine.